# How to Load disabled products last in a product collection?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I would like to load Disabled products last or bottom in a product collection in a category listing. I want some thing like enabled products followed by disabled products in a product collection. is this possible in magento?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->setOrder('status','ASC')
```

or use a *Custom Design --> Custom layout update* for this category with something like:

```
<reference name="product_list">
  <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
</reference>
```

Which would include to have the *status* as the default product listing in the Display Settings of that category. You would need to make the `status`-attribute to be available as `Used for Sorting in Product Listing` before you can choose it as default sort order.